# How can I run ipynb file in Github in some period via Github Action

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, github-actions

I want to run periodically ipynb file in my github repository (Like every 30 minutes).

I know that I can use Github Action to create yml file for this progress but I have no idea how to reorganize yml file.

How can I do it?

Here is my test tml file defined below.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/5 * * * *'
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Runs a single command using the runners shell
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!

    # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        echo Add other actions to build,
        echo test, and deploy your project.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [GitHub action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-notebook) that runs your jupyter notebook and lets you upload the artifacts. As for how to organize your workflow file, you can read the [documentation here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/configuring-a-workflow).